# how to write code with class and description rdf

Tags: rdf

I am new to RDF. I have created class book with one property ISBN. I would like to use Description to fill it wit data. However my code is not working. Any ideas why?

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<rdf:RDF
       xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
       xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#">

<rdfs:Class rdf:ID="book">
   <rdfs:comment>The class of books</rdfs:comment>
</rdfs:Class>

<rdfs:Property rdf:ID="ISBN">
  <rdfs:comment>
     It is a property of books and takes literals as values.
  </rdfs:comment>
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#book"/>
</rdfs:Property>

<rdf:Description rdf:ID="12345">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="&mydomain ; book"/>
   <mydomain:ISBN> abc567 </mydomain:ISBN>
</rdf : Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable as written, we can't possibly tell what is wrong with your code without seeing your code!  Also what is the data you have shown - is it your input, output, desired output?  You also need to describe what your expected output is (preferably including an example)

Answer (score 0):

You have several typos in the rdf code:

1. Identifier URIs should not start with a number
2. The "mydomain" namespace is not declared
3. There is an extra space when closing the rdf description.

The following code would be correct:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<rdf:RDF
       xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
       xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
       xmlns:mydomain="http://example.org#"
>

<rdfs:Class rdf:ID="book">
   <rdfs:comment>The class of books</rdfs:comment>
</rdfs:Class>

<rdfs:Property rdf:ID="ISBN">
  <rdfs:comment>
     It is a property of books and takes literals as values.
  </rdfs:comment>
  <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#book"/>
</rdfs:Property>

<rdf:Description rdf:ID="a12345">
  <rdf:type rdf:resource="#book"/>
   <mydomain:ISBN> abc567 </mydomain:ISBN>
</rdf:Description>

</rdf:RDF>
```

In the future, you can use this link: http://www.w3.org/RDF/Validator/ to validate your RDF. I hope this answers your querstion.